# PHP not using custom php.ini file

Tags: php, windows, apache

I have done this before so I'm not sure why it's not working, but I am trying to create a custom `php.ini` file and I have placed this within a specific directory.

For example, the default `php.ini` is located at:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.ini
```

My custom one is located at:

```
D:\Codebase\Somedir\123\php.ini
```

I placed a PHP file inside the above directory and did output with `phpinfo()` and it still reports it as using `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`.

I have restarted Apache as well.

What am I doing wrong here!?

Answer (score 1):

You can see which php.ini file is loaded running `php.exe --ini`. On my computer it output:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\tools\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

If it is the wrong php.ini there, have a look to http://php.net/configuration.file

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XAMPP you can change the configuration file it loads PHP with by opening the properties.ini file in the

```
C:\xamp
```

directory and editing the php_configuration_directory field to

```
D:\Codebase\Somedir\123\
```

Then restart apache for the changes to take effect.

If PHP is running as an apache module you could also edit httpd.conf on your apache setup and add this variable:

```
PHPIniDir "D:\Codebase\Somedir\123\"
```

Comment: wouldn't that change the php.ini file for everything? I only want to use this custom php.ini for this particular directory.